# How to pass two variables from form select using POST method?

Tags: php, sql

```
    Supplier:* <br/><select name="supplier">
<?php foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['supplier_id']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row['supplier_name']; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Retrieving data on the next php script:

```
$supplier_name = ??????
$supplier_id = ?????
```

The above code is allowing a user to make a selection of a supplier from a supplier table.

How can I pass both the supplier_name and the associated supplier_id to two different variable from the form using POST?

Comment: Do you really have to?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. The form submits `supplier_id`, which you can then use to look up the supplier_name in your code. If you want to get both from your form, that leaves open the possibility that someone hack your form and put in `42 = nasty ugly language` instead of the expected `42 = acme inc.`

Comment: I am not suppose to modify the design of the database but i should pass along the supplier_id as well so yes i have to because the supplier_name is already being used and i would have to overhaul too many php scripts if i was to stop passing it along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bellow you have a quick example. It's not the case to use hidden input elements.

**Your select:**

```
<select name="supplier">
<?php foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['supplier_id'] .'|' . $row['supplier_name']; ?>">
          <?php echo $row['supplier_name']; ?>
     </option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

**Php script that processes the form:**

```
if(isset($_POST['supplier']) {
    $arr = explode('|', $_POST[supplier]);

   if( count($arr) == 2 ) {
       $supplierId = $arr[0];
       $supplierName = $arr[1];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank but it is not functioning i get : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected { on line 9 : if(isset($_POST[supplier]) {

Comment: put the quote $_POST['supplier']...  my mistake but try not only to use copy & paste

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to do something like:

```
 <option value="<?php echo $row['supplier_id'].';'.$row['supplier_name']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['supplier_name']; ?>
                </option>
```

And then evaluate them like so:

```
$values = explode( ';', $_POST['supplier_info'] );
$supplier_id = $values[0];
$supplier_name = $values[1];
```

But it would be better to only transmit the id and then llokup the name of the supplier when evaluating the $_POST-Data

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE)  on line 9 : $values = explode( ';' $_POST['supplier_info'] );

Comment: forgot the comma, edited it. Pay attention that you name the parameter correct - what i have called `$_POST['supplier_info']` is the name of your `<select>`!

Comment: new problem, Notice: Undefined offset: 1  on line 11: @ $supplier_name = $values[1];

Comment: Are you sure you edited everything? Do not just copy and paste code! Did you insert the same delimiter between your values? Try to echo your `$_POST['supplier_info']`.